# cannot move out of `encoded_packet`, a captured variable in an `Fn`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to move something received through a parameter on a closure. Since it's received and not borrowed, I should be able to do whatever I want with it. However, it's preventing me from moving `encoded_packet` outside of the closure:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct EncodedPacket {}

fn main() {
    let produce = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(
        move |encoded_packet: EncodedPacket| {
            let consume: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync> =
                Arc::new(move || -> Option<EncodedPacket> { Some(encoded_packet) });
            consume();
        },
    )));
    (produce.lock().unwrap())(EncodedPacket {});
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=512c114c3e23909a12cebefd1e5f7f86)

Error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `encoded_packet`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
 --> src/main.rs:9:66
  |
7 |         move |encoded_packet: EncodedPacket| {
  |               -------------- captured outer variable
8 |             let consume: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync> =
9 |                 Arc::new(move || -> Option<EncodedPacket> { Some(encoded_packet) });
  |                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `encoded_packet` has type `EncodedPacket`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I thought I could do whatever I wanted with `encoded_packet` since it's moved to the closure and not borrowed.

Comment: `Fn`s can be called many times, what would be returned on subsequent calls if the value was moved by the previous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is referring to the inner closure, not the outer one. It occurs because *if* the inner function were called a second time, it would no longer have an `EncodedPacket` to return.

To help with this situation, Rust has a way to express “functions callable only once, perhaps because they move things out of themselves”: use `FnOnce` instead of `Fn`.

However, that will not work in your application, because calling a `FnOnce` moves (consumes) *the function,* thus expressing the constraint the function can only be called once — but you're putting the function in an `Arc`, which cannot in general be moved out of.

If you want the function to be usable more than once, then you must do something to be able to produce more than one packet, like implementing and using `Clone` for `EncodedPacket`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct EncodedPacket { /* ... */ }
// ...
            Arc::new(move || -> Option<EncodedPacket> {
                Some(encoded_packet.clone())
            });
```

If you only need the function to be usable once, then just change the type to `Box<dyn FnOnce() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send>` — the `FnOnce` instead of `Fn` allows it to move things out of itself, and the `Box` instead of `Arc` allows the function to be itself consumed.

If you absolutely must have the function implement `Fn` or be wrapped in `Arc` (because some other code requires it) and want it to only work once and panic if called a second time, then store the packet inside an `Option` and use [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to retrieve it:

```rust
let mut encoded_packet = Some(encoded_packet);
let consume: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync> = 
Arc::new(move || -> Option<EncodedPacket> {
    Some(encoded_packet.take().expect("Packet already taken"))
});
```